# A zmq subscriber unable to subscribe to the published messages if socket.send() was used only once

Tags: node.js, zeromq, publish-subscribe

A `zmq` subscriber fails to subscribe to the message if `socket.send()` is used **only once** in publisher. 
Subscriber was able to subscribe to the messages when the following code is used in publisher:

```
var zmq = require('zmq')
  , sock = zmq.socket('pub')

sock.bindSync('tcp://127.0.0.1:3000');
var message = {"test" : true};
setInterval(function(){
    sock.send(['notify_anomaly', JSON.stringify(message)]);
},1000);
```

But it doesn't work if `setInterval` is removed in the publisher code, as follows:

```
var zmq = require('zmq')
  , sock = zmq.socket('pub')

sock.bindSync('tcp://127.0.0.1:3000');
var message = {"test" : true};
sock.send(['notify_anomaly', JSON.stringify(message)]);
```

Comment: So don't remove `setInterval` then? Coincidentally, my computer stops working if I pull the power cord.

Comment: I believe this is the "slow joiner" problem. The subscriber will always miss the first messages unless the publisher waits to send until the subscriber is connected. http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#toc13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Well, not exactly, Sir.

**Historically,**
 ZeroMQ used a **`SUB`**-side subscription ( topic-filtering ). That means two things. **`PUB`**-lisher has zero knowledge of who `SUB`'ed to what & spends Zero-effort on topic-filter processing. Plus, it pours and has to do so, all messages onto all diverse transport-class channels down the road, towards ( only down-there topic-filtering ) `SUB`-scribers ( which principally creates some level of inefficiency on the transport-layers resources ).

So, if your code uses "old" ZeroMQ wrapper / language-binding, your "PUB-lisher" is out of question not the root-cause of the problem, as it by-design does not care about any, including "late-SUBscriber", counterparties. The time-delay helps ( not the **`PUB.send()`**, but the

```
// unknown SUB code, a default SUB-state is TOPIC-FILTER throws everything, YES !
//                                                       THROWS EVERYTHING AWAY
SUB.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE,
                "<some_TOPIC_FILTER_string_to_be_used_after_this_happens_in_time"
                );
```

So this has nothing to do with the code per-se on the **`PUB`** side, Q.E.D., but designers have to bear the timing-coincidences in mind, if designing robust app-architectures.

**Next,**
 the newer ZeroMQ versions have switched to **`PUB`**-side filtering. This seems as a major change, but it does not have any great implications into your example.

**`PUB`**-side filtering has just removed the transport-layer congestions by centralised topic-filtering on the `PUB`-side, at a cost of sum-of-(so-far-cheap-'cause-distributed)-workloads, that now reside, concentrated, on the `PUB`-side.

So, your observation still shows not receiving any message on `SUB`-side, so why going into such details? Well, now, in the case of the newer version, if the `SUB` did not manage to **"tell & deliver"** it's `SUB`-scription preferences to the **`PUB`**-side, before that one had already dispatched the `PUB.send( aFirstMESSAGE_to_Those_whom_I_know_they_SUBed_to_this_TOPICFILTER )` 
there would be no music down the road at all, again, due to **timing-coincidence** of the distributed system events' propagation & delivery in time and **not due to a `PUB`-side ( only ) code tweaking**.

### Epilogue:

In either case, ZeroMQ is a broker-less messaging framework. That means, persistence of messages is not even intended to create, nor provided. Each of the Scaleable Formal Communication Pattern's behavioural archetype node has clearly specified in API-documentation, buffer-management and message-{ retain | discard } and other rules. Be sure to check also the different versions of ZeroMQ low-level protocol, that is being used on all nodes of your distributed system realm ( typically one cannot control that, but may design version-aware behavioral policy enforcements to handle this sort of production ecosystem uncertainties ).

### The
Best
Next
Step:

> If one strives to remain some time in an area of a professional design of distributed systems, the best thing one can do is to read the fabulous book from one of the ZeroMQ fathers, Pieter HINTJENS ( [may check other post on **ZeroMQ** and follow the **direct link to the book's PDF**-version](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20[ZeroMQ]%20pdf) ).

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of the "slow joiner" problem.

Here is a quote from the [guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#toc13):

> There is one more important thing to know about PUB-SUB sockets: you
>   do not know precisely when a subscriber starts to get messages. Even
>   if you start a subscriber, wait a while, and then start the publisher,
>   the subscriber will always miss the first messages that the publisher
>   sends. This is because as the subscriber connects to the publisher
>   (something that takes a small but non-zero time), the publisher may
>   already be sending messages out.

Basically, when the publisher runs, it has a handshake with the subscribers. Since that is asynchronous, the publisher may finish sending the messages before the handshake is complete. In that case the subscribers will miss the messages. To get the subscriber to get the first message, the publisher needs to wait to send until it is sure the subscriber is connected.

Here is a further quote:

> In Chapter 2 - Sockets and Patterns we'll explain how to synchronize a
>   publisher and subscribers so that you don't start to publish data
>   until the subscribers really are connected and ready.

It shows how you can use another socket pair using REQ-REP to signal when the subscriber is ready to receive on the subscibe socket [here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Node-Coordination).